# Extracting table info using BeautifulSoup (bs4)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Could anyone please give me a snippet of BeautifulSoup code to extract some of the items in the table found [here](http://biology.burke.washington.edu/conus/recordview/record.php?ID=1ll&tabs=21100111&frms=1&res=&pglimit=A)?

Here's my attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = "http://biology.burke.washington.edu/conus/accounts/../recordview/record.php?ID=1ll&tabs=21100111&frms=1&res=&pglimit=A"

html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
tables = soup.findAll("table")
```

However, this is failing -- tables turns out to be empty.

Sorry, I'm a BeautifulSoup noob.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given url page does not contain any table element in the source.

table is <del>generated by javascript</del> inside an iframe.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://biology.burke.washington.edu/conus/recordview/description.php?ID=1l9l0l421l55llll&tabs=21100111&frms=1&pglimit=A&offset=&res=&srt=&sql2='

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tables = soup.find_all('table')
#print(tables)
```

---

selenium solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://biology.burke.washington.edu/conus/accounts/../recordview/record.php?ID=1ll&tabs=21100111&frms=1&res=&pglimit=A"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0])
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
tables = soup.find_all('table')
#print(tables)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Ok thank you!  I didn't realize that.  Do you see the info in the box that says Shell Morphometry at the top? How would I extract the information inside that box?

Comment: Hmm, I'll consider selenium.  Is there any easy way to do it using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @littleO, With my first code, `print(len(table))` outputs `1`.

Comment: Thanks @falsetru, it looks like your solution is working!  So helpful.

Comment: I noticed that the url you use in your non-selenium code snippet isn't identical to the url I gave in my question.  This seems to make a difference for me.  How did you come up with that url?  Sorry, I'm completely new at web programming.

Comment: @littleO, Open original URL page in your browser. See the source, find `<iframe`, `src` attribute of the iframe has the url you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it worked.  Out of curiosity, can you explain why it worked when I used that other url, but not the url I had originally tried to use?

Comment: @littleO, It's better to search about `iframe` because I can't explain it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

this is my current workflow:

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
url = "http://somewebpage.com"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tables = soup.find_all('table')
```